# Can you open source part of a database and keep another part closed?

Tags: licensing

Suppose I had a table in a database. This table contains user profile information. Each profile has: Name, birthdate, username, mini-bio, gender.

**My question:**

Suppose I wanted to make the "mini bio" column open source but wanted to keep "age" closed source, could I do this?

Comment: Database licensing in general is an interesting topic - especially if you leave the "database as in mysql" definition and enter into the "database as a collection of data" definition. Gotta run, will elaborate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The old "you're the owner" comes up again... yes, you could. The only problem here is the implementation.

To implement this, you simply need to make the mini-bio column publically available, perhaps through a UI on a website. You can keep the rest of the database private. You can then say at the bottom of each page

> mini-bios licensed under cc-by-sa with attribution required

and it's open-source.